# _mm_broadcastsd_pd missing in GCC avx2intrin.h (versions X-9.2)

Tags: c++, gcc, intrinsics, avx2

just found out, that `_mm_broadcastsd_pd`, which is listed in the intel intrinsics guide ([link](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#expand=4912,3144,614,3143,4166,443,451,2431,3857,738,6144,3922,2150,5358,2150,3922,3857,3847,3857,3847,2537,3533,2537,442,447,2707,442,6098,6086,5185,6098,6041,5196,3863,3148,2942,2946,4171,3834,3846,3846,3853,3859,3849,3840,3837,3837,3863,572,572,563,4171,4202,2428,4934,4934,528,572,575,575,563,563,563&techs=MMX,SSE,SSE2,SSE3,SSSE3,SSE4_1,SSE4_2,AVX,AVX2&text=_mm_broadcastsd_pd)), is not implemented in GCCs `avx2intrin.h`. I tested a small example on Godbolt with the latest GCC version and it won't compile ([Example GCC](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'%23include+%3Cx86intrin.h%3E%0A%0A__m128d+Test(__m128d+a)%0A%7B%0A++++return+_mm_broadcastsd_pd(a)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g92,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-O3+-march%3Dskylake',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+9.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)). Clang does ([Example Clang](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'%23include+%3Cx86intrin.h%3E%0A%0A__m128d+Test(__m128d+a)%0A%7B%0A++++return+_mm_broadcastsd_pd(a)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang900,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-O3+-march%3Dskylake',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+9.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)). It's the same on my computer (GCC 8.3).

Should I file a bug report or is there any particular reason why it is not included? I mean, sure, `_mm_movedup_pd` does exactly the same thing and clang actually generates the same assembly for both intrinsics, but I think that shouldn't be a reason to exclude it.

Greetings

**Edit**

Created a bug report: [link](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=92013)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all compilers have all aliases for an intrinsic (different names for the same thing).  Other than trying them on Godbolt, IDK how to find out which ones are portable across current versions of the major 4 compilers.

But yes, GCC/clang do accept bugs about missing `_mm` intrinsics, especially ones that Intel documents.

`_mm_broadcastsd_pd` is documented by Intel as being an intrinsic for `movddup` so you're not missing out on anything.   More importantly, it's a bit misleading because there is no `vbroadcastsd xmm, xmm`, [only with a YMM or ZMM destination](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vbroadcast).  (`_mm256_broadcast_sd(double *a);`  and `_mm256_broadcastsd_pd(__m128d a);`)

The asm reference manual doesn't even document `_mm_broadcastsd_pd` in the vbroadcast or [the `movddup` entry](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/movddup); it's only in the intrinsics guide.

GCC would probably want to add this, especially since clang has it.  Having `_mm_broadcastsd_pd` as an alias would be useful for people that are looking for it and don't know the asm well enough to know that they need a `movddup`.  (Or with AVX 3-operand instructions, `movlhps` or `unpcklpd` same,same)

Comment: Thx. As you said,  I also saw that there is no `_mm256_broadcastsd_pd(__m256d)`. But that's not much of a problem since one can use a `_mm256_castpd256_pd128`. Still a little bit confusing. I 'll file a bug report and put the link into the question. Let's see what happens.

Comment: @wychmaster: There's no `_mm256_broadcastsd_pd(__m256d)` because the asm instruction is `vbroadcastsd ymm, xmm` and the intrinsics reflect that.  An SD source is a single `double`, like the low element of a `__m128d`.  That's why `_mm256_broadcastsd_pd` has a `__m128d` arg.  The `_pd` suffix means the source is the low element of a vector, as opposed to a broadcast *load* from memory, with a `double*` arg.

Comment: `__m256d _mm256_movedup_pd` is two in-lane broadcasts, not at all the same thing.

Comment: All right. I guess if one knows the corresponding asm instructions a lot of things do make more sense. Still learning the basics ;) . Filed the bug report. Link is in the question.